# upper semicontinuous function and bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0, \infty) \times [0, \infty)  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an upper semicontinuous function.

I want to ask whether the following holds:

If $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are bounded sequences in $(0, \infty)$ then  $$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n, y_n) \leq f (\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}  x_n, \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}  y_n).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $f$ be defined by $f(x,y)=-xy$, then $f$ is even continuous. Let $x_n=1$ for $n$ odd and $x_n=2$ for $n$ even. Let $y_n=2$ for $n$ odd and $y_n=1$ for $n$ even.